# Bash-Completion is broken after installation of Dotfiles

Tags: macos, bash, dotfiles

I've installed this [dotfiles-repo](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles) on a newly installed OSX Yosemite Machine. I also ran its Scripts ~/.osx and brew.sh after installing homebrew. Everything works as expected, but not in the terminal.

After reboot each terminal starts with lots of errors:

```
-bash: declare: -A: invalid option 
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
-bash: complete: -D: invalid option
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-P    prefix] [-S suffix] [-X filterpat] [-F function] [-C command] [name ...]
```

Also, when i want to use bash completion, something like this happens:

```
mv Dropb-bash: ${prev,,}: bad substitution
```

I typed "mv Dropb" and pressed the Tab-key then. The other characters "-bash: $(prev..." occur then and restricts me to use the bash completion as it was possible before installing these dotfiles.

which part of the dotfiles should i change (or delete) to fix these issues?

Answer (score 1):

As described in this [blog post](https://vinkla.com/posts/update-bash-mac-osx/), OSX Yosemite comes with an dead old BASH-Version (3.2.57 right now) which does not support some newer stuff used in the dotfiles.

While the installation-script brew.sh, which is part of the dotfiles mentioned above, installs the current bash-version (4.3.33), it is not used right now by the terminal.

The following steps will register the bash installed via brew as the system-wide-bash:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells'
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```